# SQL Join multiple ids comma separated

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i have two tables,  costs and users.

Costs table:

```
id | project | category | type | description | status | value | date_reg | date_edit | edited | id_user | name
```

Now i need, save id from users on id_user in costs table, how i do it? i save as 1|2|3 or 1,2,3 ? But i need join table users for get some infos, like name, email and others things.

Costs table:
**id_user**
1|2|3|4 or 1,2,3,4 or anything.

User table:
    **id** | name | password | email | date_reg | level | photo

Because may have many users on the same project(table costs).

**I want list users (from user table) infos by id_users on costs table.** 
I am using codeigniter.

Answer (score 1):

You need a new costs table to each cost:

```
Projects
-----------------
Project_id
Name

Users
--------------------
User_id
Username

Costs
----------------
Cost_id
Amount
Project_id
User_id
```

..

To find projects costs  per project per user:

```
Select sum(c.Amount) as total_cost, count(*) as num_costs, p.Project_id,p.Name as project_name, u.user_id, u.Username
From costs c inner join project p on c.Project_id=c.Project_id
Inner join users u
On c.User_id=u.User_id
Group by p.Project_Id, u.user_id
```

For costs per user

```
Select sum(c.Amount) as total_cost, count(*) as num_costs, u.user_id, u.Username
From costs c 
Inner join users u
On c.User_id=u.User_id
Group by u.user_id
```

Comment: I have it, but how i join user_id's with users table? join users on costs table...